MicroProfile Rest Client : how to uncompress gzip Content-Type
I'm calling an endpoint to get a CSV file :
@RegisterRestClient
@Path("/catalogs")
public interface Client {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/{catalog}/content/responses/{key}/")
    Response getResponsesKey(@PathParam("catalog") String catalog, @PathParam("key") String key);
}

When I send the request via Postman :
GET https://toto.com/catalogs/99999/content/responses/forexReport-20241204-forexReport.csv/
I get an nice csv body.
Headers are :

Content-Type : text/csv; header=present; charset=utf-8
content-disposition : attachment; filename=forexReport-20241204-forexReport.csv
content-encoding : gzip

With MicroProfile I have to manually unzip the response :
@Inject
@RestClient
private Client client;

private void toto() {
    String key = "forexReport-20241204-forexReport.csv";
    Response response = client.getResponsesKey("99999", key);
    //unzip the response
    try(GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(response.readEntity(InputStream.class));
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("foo.csv")
        ) {
        int c = 0;
        while((c = gis.read()) != -1) {
            os.write(c);
        }
    }
}

Question : is there a way to tell MicroProfile to automatically unzip the incoming file ?
I use wildfly-29.0.1.Final

Since you're using WildFly you should be able to use the @GZIP annotation. See https://docs.resteasy.dev/6.2/userguide/#_configuring.

Works nicely with org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.GZIPDecodingInterceptor. Too bad that I need to add the dependency to resteasy.

Yes. I need to understand the history on why it was done like that. I agree it seems it should be added by default. Do note on the client you can use @RegisterProvider(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.class).

MicroProfile itself does not have a built-in feature to automatically handle and unzip incoming files. You must handle the unzipping logic explicitly in your application code.
